# uipickerview with textfield not being called after textFieldShouldBeginEditing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am using `UIPickerViewDataSource`, `UIPickerViewDelegate` 
I am creating an `countrytxtfield` with `countrypickerview` and i am able to pass some static data to the `countrypickerview` and it is working fine.

But when i am trying to get the data from service response i am calling the same `countrypickerview` in `connectionDidFinishLoading` but it is not being called

According to me

I am detecting tap on the `countrytxtfield` from `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method

I am calling a method

```
[self addPickerViewCountry];
```

which has `countrytextfield` and `countrypickerview` details

If i place this method inside `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` `countrypickerview` is being called and i can see data and if place the same method after `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and in `connectionDidFinishLoading` i am unable to see `countrypickerview`

I think `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is creating a problem.

This may be simple logic to apply which i am not able to figure.Below is my code to create `countrypickerview` and when i am calling it

**viewcontroller.h file**

```
UIPickerView *myPickerViewCountry;
NSArray *pickerArrayCountry;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *country;

viewcontroller.m
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{



if( textField == _country ) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    NSString *refidUser =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                          stringForKey:@"refidUser"];
    NSLog(@"id %@",refidUser);

    NSString *editProfURL = editProfileDetails;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:editProfURL];



    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    // NSData *requestBody = [@"UserName=%@,username&Password=%@,password" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *requestBody =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"UserId=%@",refidUser];

    NSData *requestBodyy = [requestBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestBodyy];
    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError = NULL;   
}
  return YES;
  }

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[self addPickerViewCountry];
}

  -(void)addPickerViewCountry{

  pickerArrayCountry =  [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"India",
  @"India",@"India",@"India", nil];

  // pickerArrayCountry = countryNameArr;
   NSLog(@"countryarr %@",countryNameArr);
  NSLog(@"pickerarrat %@",pickerArrayCountry);
  myPickerViewCountry = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
  myPickerViewCountry.dataSource = self;
  myPickerViewCountry.delegate = self;
  myPickerViewCountry.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

   UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doneCountry:)];

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:
                      CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-
                                 myPickerViewCountry.frame.size.height-50, 320, 30)];
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         barButtonDone, nil];
[toolBar setItems:toolbarItems];
_country.inputView = myPickerViewCountry;
_country.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
 }
```

If i call the `[self addPickerViewCountry]` method in

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[self addPickerViewCountry];
 }
```

I am able to see the `UIPickerView` and if i call it in `connectionDidFinishLoading` i am unable to see the `UIPickerView`.Can anyone suggest me where the problem is?

Comment: Is connectionDidFinishLoading called?

Comment: connectionDidFinishLoading is called,and i am able to go inside the addPickerViewCountry method but numberOfComponentsInPickerView is not being called.If the method is in textFieldShouldBeginEditing it is being called and able to see pickerview

Answer (score 1):

where did you add `myPickerViewCountry`, like `[self.view addSubview: myPickerViewCountry]`? another thing is you keep on allocating new `UIPickerView`..

I think is proper if you do it like this:

```
if (myPickerViewCountry == nil)
{
  myPickerViewCountry = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
  myPickerViewCountry.dataSource = self;
  myPickerViewCountry.delegate = self;
  myPickerViewCountry.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
}
```

about your problem: You did not set a frame to your

`myPickerViewCountry = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];`

try setting like:

`myPickerViewCountry = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];`

hmm.. that's what i think is wrong..

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand that How can `connectionDidFinishLoading` method call? 
Because you never send the request on server.

You only create a `URLRequest` object inside `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method and never send it on server. So, how it is possible that `connectionDidFinishLoading` method gets call.

Can you send the the whole `.m` class. So, I will help you. Are you calling any other request in this class.

Comment: Hi kailash thanks for your reply,i am able to get reponse and everything is working fine.But my only concern is if use the method in [self addPickerViewCountry]; is being called but it is not entering into numberOfComponentsInPickerView.I think the return command in the - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField is creating a problem.

Comment: I don't think return is creating issue.

Answer (score 0):

In these lines,

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
// NSData *requestBody = [@"UserName=%@,username&Password=%@,password" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *requestBody =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"UserId=%@",refidUser];

NSData *requestBodyy = [requestBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:requestBodyy];
NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
NSError *requestError = NULL;
```

You create an `NSMutableURLRequest` but you never start the request. **I highly doubt that `-connectionDidFinishLoading` is even called**. Double check, breakpoint, and please put your full code in so that we have some context where you're doing something wrong.

Comment: thanks for your reply Schemetrical,I am getting response and i am able to see the response.Here the question is why i am unable to go inside the numberOfComponentsInPickerView

Comment: Can you update your question and use proper grammar. Its hard reading what you're trying to say, and although your english might not be perfect, you can at least format and capitalise properly :-)